# ansible jinja2 - if elseif - use the same lines

Tags: ansible, jinja2

on both condition (if, elif), it must start from the line "start-here".
How can both(if, elseif) be looped/started from the same line?

- if statement have multiple ports and will create two different config, using same config.
- elif statement have single port and will create one config, using same config

  ```
  {% for web in web_servers %}
  {% if web.web_ports == 'multi-home' %}
  {% for n in range(0, 2) %}
  {% elif web.web_ports == 'single-home' %}
  {% for n in range(0, 1) %}

  *(start-here)*
  -------------------------------------------
  ROUTER_{{ n }}
  -------------------------------------------
  {% for rtr in web['router_'~n] %}
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simplifying your logic and using a variable to hold the upper bound of your range?

For example:

```
{%- set max_range = 1 -%}
{%- if web.web_ports == 'multi-home' -%}
  {%- set max_range = 2 -%}
{%- endif -%}
{%- for n in range(0, max_range) -%}
-------------------------------------------
ROUTER_{{ n }}
-------------------------------------------
{#- your other for can still be nested here #}
{% endfor %}
```

This will give:

- ```
  -------------------------------------------
  ROUTER_0
  -------------------------------------------
  -------------------------------------------
  ROUTER_1
  -------------------------------------------
  ```

  when `web.web_ports` is equal to `multi-home`
- ```
  -------------------------------------------
  ROUTER_0
  -------------------------------------------
  ```

  when `web.web_ports` is not equal to `multi-home` (so `single-home`, but also any other possible value)

Comment: thanks, that is more simple and worked  as I expected :) 

By the way, what is the difference between {%   and   {%-

Comment: The minus on any Jinja delimiter is a [whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control) it indicates that the space and newlines otherwise created by Jinja should be trimmed